# Display UIPickerView as inputView in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

in one of my iPhone applications, I used UIPickerView as inputView for a textfield defined in a custom UITableViewCell. Once text input's shouldBeginEditing delegate is called, I call my custom delegate to set UIPickerView as inputView and a UIToolBar as inputAccessoryView for the textfield. This resulted displaying a UIPickerViewController with custom data and a toolbar with a dismiss button instead of the default soft keyboard.
I'm now porting the same application for iPad where I displayed the uiTableView with textField inside a popover controller and have to display the UIPickerView inside the same UIPopoverController. If I use the same code (i-e, setting UIPickerView as inputView of the textfield) it displays a UIPickerView in place of the soft keyboard not in the UIPopoverController. (Looks very awkward in the iPad).

Please help in this regard.